# `conda env remove` hangs for 16 hours, what are my options?

Tags: python, anaconda, freeze

At 5 PM yesterday evening, I executed:

```
(my_root) C:\Users\W>conda env remove --name py36
```

Having made no apparent progress overnight, I just killed it at 08:45 AM.

In executing the same command from the same environment (my_root), it took no more than a 5-10 minutes to remove other conda environments earlier yesterday.

Is there a more heavy-handed way to get rid of an environment from within conda or am I left with backing-up the envs I want to yml and doing a complete uninstall/reinstall of conda?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe run that command under `strace` to see what it's getting stuck on.

Comment: I think you just need to delete the folder that it's stashed in, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ 0x5453 would the syntax be  >conda strace remove -- name py36

Comment: @ Mad Physicist - I'm a bit reluctant to do that outright, but your post inspired me to consult the Windows directory (...\Anaconda3\envs\) where they live. The py36 subdirectory contained only one subdirectory ('scripts) where all of the remaning exe files had ".conda_trash" extensions (e.g. imageio_remove_bin.exe.conda_trash). Interestingly, subdirs related to envs I deleted successfully yesterday were still present with similar contents. Will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers for the quick posts...

It seems my problem is indicative of something deeper in my Conda install.

Consulting my install directory for the py36 env  (see my reply to @ Mad Physicist above) revealed most of the content was gone (all except \scripts subdir with ~20 files with *.exe.conda_trash extensions).

Exploring other \env subdirs I deleted successfully yesterday (where 'remove' ran to completion) revealed the similar contents to \envs\py36.

```
>conda env list
```

confirmed that py36 was no longer available, so I ran

```
>conda clean --yes --all
```

which also froze.

But also freed a heap of space on my hard-drive (successfully removed a mess of *.tar.bz2 files).

Conclusions:

- the original 'remove' seemed to have worked properly and (per @Mad Physicist and @Matt Messersmith) it seems to be OK to just delete the respective Windows subdirs under \envs
- because the freezing behaviour is a bit of a concern, I'll be doing a full uninstall (after yml backups), then reinstalling

Answer (score 2):

On mac/linux you can nuke the directory containing the environment, and it'll remove the environment:

```
(base) mmessersmith@blah:~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/mmessersmith/miniconda3
py2                      /home/mmessersmith/miniconda3/envs/py2
py36                     /home/mmessersmith/miniconda3/envs/py36

(base) mmessersmith@blah:~$ rm -rf  /home/mmessersmith/miniconda3/envs/py2
(base) mmessersmith@blah:~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/mmessersmith/miniconda3
py36                     /home/mmessersmith/miniconda3/envs/py36
```

Can't confirm it works on windows ATM, but should (and you don't have too much to lose by trying it if you're debating a full-reinstall anyway).